# Notification bar disappears after download is completed using DownloadManager in Android

Tags: android, notifications, download-manager

i am downloading an application in Android using the **DownloadManager** class. When the download is completed, the notification bar disappears. How to let it visible until the user click on it?

**EDIT**

I can use `VISIBILITY VISIBLE _NOTIFY COMPLETED` in API level 11 and above, but I am using API level 10. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
my_notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Put the code above when creating a Notification.